# ruby, rails gem install error - ERROR: While executing gem ... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I tried with last version with ruby, but when run gem install rails, always got an error

```
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    U+041D to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437
```

I am using windows 8.

but gem list ---local working.. only on install, my locale set english.

what kind problem is it?

Comment: Just drop the idea of developing ruby/rails on windows. If you don't want to use Linux as your primary OS then got with dual boot or some virtual machine (VirtualBox, VmWare etc).

Answer (score 14):

Use this link:
https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10300

They said that you need to chance the enconding at The registry.rb file:

Folder: Ruby2.1.0\lib\ruby\2.1.0\win32
File: registry.rb
Line: 70

```
- LOCALE = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)
+ LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8
+ #LOCALE = Encoding.find(Encoding.locale_charmap)
```

Answer (score 1):

We'll need more information to solve your problem. What command are you running?

The meaning of the exception is that some character in the gem is invalid in ibm437, a common 'extended ascii' encoding on Windows machines.

You may be to work around the problem by setting your internal encoding to UTF-8.  `Encoding.default_internal = Encoding::UTF_8`

Would you mind adding the output a running a ruby file containing just the following:

```
p [Encoding.default_external, Encoding.default_internal, __ENCODING__, Encoding.find('filesystem'), Encoding.find('locale')]
```

Thanks.  If you only do it in irb that's fine to.