# ruby Encoding::UndefinedConversionError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hi all I am trying to run my first ror app
and get the following error:

```
C:\Sites\myapp>rails server
Could not find gem 'tzinfo-data (>= 0) x86-mingw32' in the gems available on thi
s machine.
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

So I write:

```
 C:\Sites\myapp>bundle install
    DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
    Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
    Resolving dependencies...

Gem::RemoteFetcher::FetchError: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read
server certificate B: certificate verify failed (https://rubygems.org/gems/rake-
10.4.2.gem)
An error occurred while installing rake (10.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
```

And in the end:

```
C:\Sites\myapp>gem install rake -v '10.4.2'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
    U+041D to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437
```

As you can see I am using windows.Windows 8 32 bit.

I found this answer: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27325245/ruby-rails-gem-install-error-error-while-executing-gem-encodingundefi)

Any other ways?

Comment: Have a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10246023/bundle-install-fails-with-ssl-certificate-verification-error Or try changing 'https://rubygems.org' to 'http://rubygems.org'.

Answer (score 0):

Use: 1.rubyinstaller-1.9.3-p551.exe instead of rubyinstaller-2.1.6.exe or ..
2.Default directory C:\Ruby193\
I just resolved this problem at win-7 32bit.