# gem install jekyll failure

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am installing Jekyll via gem. After I install the Ruby following this instruction https://learn.cloudcannon.com/jekyll/install-jekyll-on-windows/ and  type the "gem install jekyll" in cmd, I get the error below:

```
C:\Windows\system32>gem install jekyll
Traceback (most recent call last):
    15: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `<internal:gem_prelude>'
    14: from <internal:gem_prelude>:2:in `require'
    13: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1388:in `<top (required)>'
    12: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems.rb:1388:in `require'
    11: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
    10: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/singleton.rb:27:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
     9: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:96:in `enable_dll_search_paths'
     8: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:86:in `mingw_bin_path'
     7: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:73:in `msys_path'
     6: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:48:in `iterate_msys_paths'
     5: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:542:in `open'
     4: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:435:in `open'
     3: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.5.0/ruby_installer/runtime/msys2_installation.rb:49:in `block in iterate_msys_paths'
     2: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:611:in `each_key'
     1: from C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:910:in `export_string'
C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb:910:in `encode': U+7F51 to IBM437 in conversion from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 to IBM437 (Encoding::UndefinedConversionError)
```

The steps I followed are below:

```
@powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "iex ((new-object net.webclient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))" && SET PATH=%PATH%;%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\chocolatey\bin

choco install ruby -y

gem install jekyll
```

Comment: I have edited your post for you to convert the output to a code block. I recommend that you read [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) for future posts or updates, because properly formatting your examples are a crucial part of getting a response on stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you anothermh! It's my second time to post my question and I appreciate your link for formatting things

Answer (score 0):

Open the file `C:/tools/ruby25/lib/ruby/2.5.0/win32/registry.rb` in a text editor. Locate the line that begins with `LOCALE = Encoding`. Change this line from whatever it is to `LOCALE = Encoding::UTF_8`, save the file, and then retry your `gem install jekyll` operation.

There is a substantially similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27325245/3784008) here already and [some](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10300) [bugs](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/13831) on the Ruby tracker but they are not easily discovered.

If this solution doesn't work then try running the command `chcp 1256` or `chcp 1252` in your `cmd.exe` window. This will change the code page in use and may also resolve this issue.